# Trying to hide a block of items so it appears when a particular textbox is clicked,

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to hide a block of items so it appears when a particular textbox is clicked, 
it works for the first item and doesnt foe the rest, i need help to get the other id's hide on page load, then appear when the textbox closest to it with an id =Control

```
                    <html>
                    <body>
                    <table>
                    <tr>
                            <td><label>Approved Within 24HRS:</label></td>
                            <td><input name = "LLC_Veri_Approved" type = "text" size = "20" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td><label>Not Approved:</label></td>
                            <td><input id = "control" name = "LLC_Veri_NotApproved" type = "text" size = "20" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>

                    <h4>Number Of Verifications(LLC) Not Approved Reasons</h4>
                    <table id="Rtable">
                    <tr>
                            <td><label>No Receipt Attached:</label></td>
                            <td><input name = "LLC_No_Receipt" type = "text" size = "20" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td><label>No Stamp Duty:</label></td>
                            <td><input name = "LLC_No_Stamp" type = "text" size = "20" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>

                    <table>
                    <tr>
                            <td><label>Approved Within 24HRS:</label></td>
                            <td><input name = "LLC_Veri_Approved" type = "text" size = "20" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td><label>Not Approved:</label></td>
                            <td><input id = "control" name = "LLC_Veri_NotApproved" type = "text" size = "20" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>

                    <h4>Number Of Verifications(BN) Not Approved Reasons</h4>
                    <table id="Rtable">
                    <tr>
                            <td><label>No Receipt Attached:</label></td>
                            <td><input name = "BN_No_Receipt" type = "text" size = "20" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td><label>No Stamp Duty:</label></td>
                            <td><input name = "BN_No_Stamp" type = "text" size = "20" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>

                    <table>
                    <tr>
                            <td><label>Approved Within 24HRS:</label></td>
                            <td><input name = "IT_Veri_Approved" type = "text" size = "20" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td><label>Not Approved:</label></td>
                            <td><input id = "control" name = "IT_Veri_NotApproved" type = "text" size = "20" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>

                    <h4>Number Of Verifications(IT) Not Approved Reasons</h4>
                    <table id="Rtable">
                    <tr>
                            <td><label>No Receipt Attached:</label></td>
                            <td><input name = "IT_No_Receipt" type = "text" size = "20" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td><label>No Stamp Duty:</label></td>
                            <td><input name = "IT_No_Stamp" type = "text" size = "20" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
            </body>
            <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){
    //trying to hide all the tables with id=Rtable but works only for the first
    $('#Rtable').hide();

     //when you click on any of the textboxes with id = control
     $('#control').on('click', function(){
        $('#Rtable').show();
     });



});

            </script>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Id must be unique, use classes instead of ids for `control` and `Rtable` elements:

```
<input class="control" name="IT_Veri_NotApproved" type="text" size="20" />
```

JS:

```
$('.control').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('table').nextAll('.Rtable:first').show();
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3ctgnmLy/

Comment: it managed to hide all the Rtables but on clicking any of the textboxes with class or id = control all the Rtables display at once